# benefit of SAS controller over typical SATA

Tags: sas, sata

as a home user who uses Windows 10 Home Edition more than 90% of the time with a GTX970 and playing steam games what practical benefit would an economical SAS controller provide if any?

*yes, I would reinstall win10 on a new SAS SSD*

I am planning on rebuilding / modding my existing home pc (Asrock Extreme4) to be more work at home friendly and I want to support SAS, mainly 2.5" SAS SSD's and maybe 3.5" SAS HDD's if I can find trayless docks I like to make use of disks without having to open up pc case and without having to touch a screwdriver... I do a lot of linux stuff which will be on a separate disk, preferably an SSD and while usually SATA I want to be able to accommodate SAS.

Answer (score 2):

SAS more or less yields higher performance along with increased reliability compared to SATA. SATA is the "budget/standard" option where SAS is the "enterprise" option. This is why *most* servers use SAS controllers for their drives. I don't know the exact numbers, but I believe SAS is about twice the speed of SATA. SAS is pretty overkill for home-use, but if you're an enthusiast then go for it.